# input element not working on IE

Tags: html, input, requiredfieldvalidator

I realise that the HTML5 elements do not work on IE. ELements such as required placeholder are not working on IE. I found a javascript to make the placeholder work already but I would like to ask if is there any javascript coding to make the required attribute work as well??

Cheers!

My code:

```
    <input required="required" type="password" name="password" id="password" class="regfields"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this js refrence :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

and try this:

```
<form id="myform">
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        debug: true,
        success: "valid"
    }); ;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myform").validate({
            rules: {
                field: "required"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<label for="field">
    Required:
</label>
<input class="left" id="field" name="field" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Validate!" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find some useful polifills here : https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills. FORM polifill will give you the HTML5 FORM facilities even in IE. Maybe this is what you need : http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/07/27/cross-browser-html5-forms-using-modernizr-webforms2-and-html5widgets/